# react/ state not being updated because of cleanup

Tags: reactjs

I have custom hook that adds user info for posts created. And if I don't add cleanup it works as intended. I create new post, press post and it gets added to screen, but with if(mounted.current)setState() it does not update, only on refresh. What could be the problem and how could I fix it?

```js
const AllPostsAssign = () => {
  const { userPosts, allUsers } = useData();
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState();
  const mounted = useRef(true);

  // map existing posts and add user object and post id into post object.
  useEffect(() => {
    const postsWithUsers = allUsers.map((y) => {
      const usersAssignedToPosts = userPosts.map((x) => {
        if (y.userId === x.data().userId) {
          const q = Object.assign(x.data(), { id: x.id });
          const z = Object.assign(q, { user: y });
          return z;
        }
      });
      return usersAssignedToPosts;
    });
    const noUndefined = postsWithUsers.flat().filter((post) => post);

// without mounted.current it works.
    if (noUndefined && mounted.current) setPosts(noUndefined);

    console.log(mounted.current);
    console.log(posts);

    return () => (mounted.current = false);
  }, [userPosts, allUsers]);

  // sort by time created and then reverse, so newest posts would be on top.
  posts &&
    posts.sort((a, b) => {
      return a.createdAt.seconds - b.createdAt.seconds;
    });
  posts && posts.reverse();
  return posts;
};

export default AllPostsAssign;
```

Comment: what is the purpose of using `mounted` ref?

Comment: I fixed it by adding mounted.current = true; at the top of useEffect, is that a good approach?

Comment: It is to clean my posts state, when I change pages or and need to stop updating state, If I understand correctly how cleanup is done.

Comment: Cleaning your `posts` state can be simpler I believe. You can just write `const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);` Why cleaning posts using ref?

Comment: @MohammadAbdulAlim, this pattern is to avoid memory leaks within your application. So, for example, if you fetch asynchronous data and then set it to some state, it can cause memory leaks if the component gets unmounted meanwhile. So with that variable, you check if the component is still mounted after having fetched those data, so to assign it to a state only if the component is still there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have your `mounted` check declared directly inside your `useEffect`, as such:

```js
  useEffect(() => {
   let mounted = true;

    const postsWithUsers = allUsers.map((y) => {
      const usersAssignedToPosts = userPosts.map((x) => {
        if (y.userId === x.data().userId) {
          const q = Object.assign(x.data(), { id: x.id });
          const z = Object.assign(q, { user: y });
          return z;
        }
      });
      return usersAssignedToPosts;
    });
    const noUndefined = postsWithUsers.flat().filter((post) => post);

// without mounted.current it works.
    if (noUndefined && mounted) setPosts(noUndefined);

    console.log(mounted);
    console.log(posts);

    return () => (mounted = false);
  }, [userPosts, allUsers]);
```